# How to configure Yum to update from self-hosted repository

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, repository

I've been looking for help on this question for a while now-
I have a redhat instance (which I'll call "A"), that I would like to use as a repository for updates, rather than the redhat-subscription-manager. I also have another redhat instance ("B"), that I would like to point to "A" to get updates from.

The tutorials I've followed thus far have gotten me to the point that I've created a repo on "A", but I can't figure any further than that, along with how to update the packages in said repo.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Artifactory. It's a cross-platform yum repository manager that allows you to create local (hosted) as well as remote (proxy) yum repositories.

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind  [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>